# Why does YouTube Data API search often find 0 results while a normal YouTube website search yields many results?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using YouTube Data API to show product review videos on product pages of our price comparison website. We basically grab a product title and append "review" to it. The problem is that very often we do not get any results from the API, while a normal YouTube website search yields many results.

For example, the following request, when searching for "*Reiskussen Intex Downy Opblaasbaar Blauw review*" (using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true) form in the docs) does not give us any results:

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Reiskussen%20Intex%20Downy%20Opblaasbaar%20Blauw%20review&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Reiskussen%20Intex%20Downy%20Opblaasbaar%20Blauw%20review&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

This is the JSON response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "z1qySaHHjn5TA8Vggil4LrmXKdc",
  "regionCode": "NL",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": []
}
```

When we search on Youtube, we get several (relevant) results:
[image: YouTube search]

Why does the YouTube website find results and our API call does not? Is there any way to have the API find the same results or any result at all?

Comment: *if possible*, remove the `regionCode` and try again. I don't think is there any official statement about this - YouTube Data API is not being updated. My best guesses could be that you need to set more filters in your search.

Comment: `regionCode`'s default value is `US`, which also doesn't give any results unfortunately. I've also tried to play around with the other filters, but none helped so far. Thanks anyway.

Comment: any updates here? facing same issue